# Auto Suggest not working in Xcode 9.4.1

Tags: xcode, xcode9.4

AM using Xcode 9.4.1. 
The auto suggest is not working.
I ahem tried almost all possible suggestions like:
1. Cleaning the code
2. Deleting the derived data
3. Checking and unchecking the auto suggestion option in the Xcode preferences.

Please help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: I have similar problem quite often. 

My only solution is to restart XCode. It starts working for some time and then has problems again.

Comment: It is never working for me. The problem is only with my project code(which works in others system.). When I try to create a new project its working.

Comment: That's worse. I can't help, but maybe reinstall xCode?